# How to take the inverse FFT of Welch's power spectral density in Python?

Tags: fft, frequency-spectrum, python, power-spectral-density, ifft

I have calculated the power spectral density of a weakly-stationary signal using Welch's method (as implemented by [scipy.signal.welch](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.signal.welch.html) in Python), and am looking to take the inverse Fourier transform of this PSD to find the autocorrelation of the function.

(The reason why I'm not calculating the autocorrelation from the signal directly is because I'm applying transformations to the original PSD, which will yield autocorrelations different than that of the signal.)

`signal.welch` returns two arrays: one of positive frequencies and the other of the corresponding amplitudes. I figured from this that one could apply [numpy.fft.irfft](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.fft.irfft.html?highlight=irfft#numpy.fft.irfft) to the amplitude array to find the autocorrelation of the signal behind the PSD.

I am having trouble accomplishing this, however. With an amplitude array `a` from `signal.welch`, my method has been to apply `irfft(a)` and plot over the time-domain of the original signal. This is not yielding what I'm expecting (as there is appearing an unexpected symmetry in the time-domain, among other artifacts).

My question boils down to: how does the inverse FFT (calculated using `fft.irfft`) of an array `a` of positive frequency amplitudes calculated from `signal.welch` map to the time-domain of the original signal?